# Does any $d$-regular simple graph $G$ contain a $k$-regular subgraph where $1\le k \le d$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

It is easy to show if $G$ is bipartite, but I don't know if it is true in the non-bipartite case. Of course, there is an odd cycle in $G$, and in the non-trivial case where $k\ge 2$, the subgraph (if it exists) would also have a cycle. My idea for constructing a counter-example is to have $G$ with very high girth. Maybe then we cannot have a $k$-regular subgraph with a significantly smaller number of vertices. I could also use the fact that there exist graphs with arbitrarily large girth and chromatic number. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d$ and $k$ are both even then it follows from [Petersen's 2-factorization theorem](https://(en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#2-factorization)) that there is a *spanning* $k$-regular subgraph. Relatedly, if $d = 2k$ (but $k$ may be odd) you can get a spanning $k$-regular subgraph by taking every other edge of an Euler circuit.

Apparently it was a famous conjecture of Berge and Sauer that every $4$-regular graph has a $3$-regular subgraph. This conjecture was proved by Taskinov (1982).

It is not in general true that a $d$-regular graph has a $(d-1)$-regular subgraph. A counterexample is the complete $3$-partite graph $K_{3,3,3}$, which is $6$-regular but has no $5$-regular subgraph.

Proof that $K_{3,3,3}$ does not have a $5$-regular subgraph: Let the vertex classes be $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\},\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$. Suppose $G \subseteq K_{3,3,3}$ is $5$-regular. Since $G$ must have an even number of vertices, $G$ must omit at least one vertex, without loss of generality $u_1$. Since $G$ is $5$-regular, it follows that each $v_i$ is joined to each $w_i$ and to $u_2,u_3$, and likewise each $w_i$ must be joined to each $v_i$ and $u_2,u_2$, but then $u_2,u_3$ have degree $6$.